# Project structure to graphical layout (VSCode)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, treeview, structure, diagram

Is there an extension or something that could help me to visually represent the project tree structure of a large project folders (components)? For example if I have react/apps/components/... to export it to a structure graphical view something like this, directly from VSCode:

[image]

**UPDATE:** I have found a way to export project tree structure in textual format like shown below using **project-tree** VSCode extension, but it's still not what I was looking for. Maybe something to export this format to graphical?

```
├─ apps
│  ├─ one
│  │  ├─ a
│  │  ├─ b
│  │  ├─ c
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the VS code extension project-tree. I installed it, and it seems be working just fine. The drawback is that it doesn't update as you go and change the project structure. You have to cmd + shift + P and run the extension again to get an updated one.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the text representation you can export from VSCode, I think it would be easy to write a script that turns that text representation into a Mermaid graph.

Mermaid is a markdown-like language that allows you to create graphics using text.

The example that you provided could be translated into Mermaid's syntax:

```
graph LR
    Apps --> One
    One --> A
    One --> B
    One --> C
```

- graph LR states that this is a graph that will be plotted from left to right.
- Each A --> B line establishes a relationship between two elements that will be drawn.

I don't have enough reputation to post the resulting image, but you can open this site and paste the code to see it: https://mermaid.live/